# jsoup extracting all the text between tag except for one type of subtag

Tags: regex, jsoup

I have an HTML code like this

```
<p>
   <i>One</i> - <i>Two</i> - ... <i>N</i> - 
   <tag1>hey</tag1> <tag2>there!</tag2> how are you?
</p>
```

I would like to have `hey there! how are you?`.

This is what I managed to be so far:

```
Elements p = document.select("p");
List<Node> nodes = p.get(0).childNodes();
for (Node node : nodes){
    if (node.nodeName() != "i"){
        if (node.nodeName() != "#text"){
            System.out.print(((Element) node).text());
        } else {
            System.out.print(node);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what I got :

```
 - - hey there! how are you?
```

After that, I planned to use `.replace()` to get rid of the " - ".

I was wondering if there was a better way?

Comment: Of significance in the edited version is that _all_ of the text elements to exclude are preceded by an `<i>` tag. Is that correct?

Comment: The text elements to be excluded are all the "<i>smth</i> - " pattern :)

Comment: It only shows "there!". That's okay, I am going to stay with my method until there's an improvement :)

Answer (score 0):

If the layout is  sure to be as given, then this variation might do the trick for you. Testing for the `<i>` elements and elements that follow them.

```
Element p = document.select("p");
List<Node> nodes = p.childNodes();
for (Node node : nodes){
    if ((node.nodeName() != "i") && (node.previousSibling.nodeName() != "i")){
        if (node.nodeName() != "#text"){
            System.out.print(((Element) node).text());
        }else{
            System.out.print(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The layout is not exactly like this : <i>One</i> - can be repeated. (0, 1, 2 or 3 times)
I will modify my previous post consequently.
But my question was more if there were any methods from jSoup that could do it directly?